# Shopware 6 unable to sent Email

Tags: email, shopware6

I installed and configured Shopware 6.
**I configured Emails under Settings → System → Mailer** (URL …/admin#/sw/settings/mailer/index)

Unfortunately **Emails are still not sent** (e.g. Order confirmation or Contact form)

In **var/log/prod-2023-01-15.log** is see the following line :

[2023-01-15T16:26:33.140153+00:00] app.ERROR: Could not send mail: Failed sending mail to following recipients: {{ recipients }} with Error: Expected response code „250“ but got c ode „550“, with message „550 5.7.1 **Sender mismatch**“. Error Code:0 Template data: {„recipients“:{„thorsten.niehues@posteo.net“:"thorsten.niehues@posteo.net"},„senderName“:„{{ sale sChannel.name }}“,„salesChannelId“:„c6aa23ebbf0b48d490237ff19bdb47b3“,„templateId“:„5e09e2c5fdb248da8329b09b16d8b6ef“,„customFields“:null,„contentHtml“:„\n

\n The following Message was sent to you via the contact form.
\n 
\n Contact name: {{ contactFormData.firstName }} {{ contactFormData.lastName }}\n 
\n Contact email address: {{ contactFormData.email }}\n 
\n Phone: {{ contactFormData.phone }}
\n 
\n Subject: {{ contactFormData.subject }}
\n 
\n Message:
\n {{ contactFormData.comment|nl2br }}
\n

\n\n“, „contentPlain“:„The following Message was sent to you via the contact form.\n\nContact name: {{ contactFormData.firstName }} {{ contactFormData.lastName }}\nContact email address: {{ contactFormData.email }}\nPhone: {{ contactFormData.phone }}\n\nSubject: {{ contactFormData.subject }}\n\nMessage:\n{{ contactFormData.comment }}\n“,„subject“:„Contact form re ceived - {{ salesChannel.name }}“,„mediaIds“:}

I tried to remove all variables form the template to make sure it is not a template issue … but then I still get the error :

[2023-01-15T16:32:14.098476+00:00] app.ERROR: Could not send mail: Failed sending mail to following recipients: {{ recipients }} with Error: Expected response code „250“ but got c ode „550“, with message „550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch“. Error Code:0 Template data: {„recipients“:{„thorsten.niehues@posteo.net“:"thorsten.niehues@posteo.net"},„senderName“:„PlsUseV ariable“,„salesChannelId“:„c6aa23ebbf0b48d490237ff19bdb47b3“,„templateId“:„5e09e2c5fdb248da8329b09b16d8b6ef“,„customFields“:null,„contentHtml“:„Test Contact Form / Email (HTML)“, „contentPlain“:„Test Contact Form / Email (Plain)“,„subject“:„Contact Request“,„mediaIds“:}

Comment: I also asked on https://forum.shopware.com/t/emails-are-not-sent/98016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch` is an error returned by the mail server and means that the mail was rejected. This could be because the mail data is either incomplete or violates some security settings of the mail server.

Since it specifically mentions the sender, have you made sure that the mail of the sender is set? By default it should use the address set in the settings of the administration. Have a look at what is set for the *Shop owners email address* at *Settings* > *Basic information* in the administration and verify that it is a valid email address. You can also read the value of the setting quickly by using the CLI:

```bash
bin/console system:config:get core.basicInformation.email
```

Likewise you can also write the setting from the CLI:

```bash
bin/console system:config:set core.basicInformation.email doNotReply@localhost.com
```

Note: You can also set a reply-to address in the mailer settings `core.mailerSettings.senderAddress` but the address set in the basic information has priority and will be used instead unless it is empty. See the corresponding code [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.18.0/src/Core/Content/Mail/Service/MailService.php#L231).

Comment: oh wow .. the basic setting was different to the email server config (since I created a new e-mail) thx a lot :)